# iOS 10 making HTTP POST when app is in background

Tags: ios, background, alamofire

I'm relatively new to iOS development and I'm working on a Swift 3 / iOS 10 app that collects GPS location data and displays the user's position on a map.  The app also sends the location data to a web server via HTTP POST.  Transmission of the data happens on a user-configurable interval and ranges from once a minute up to once an hour.  In a nutshell, this is basically what I'm doing:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if let location = locations.last {
        // determine if it's time to send the location data
        // if so, create new job and send it to job manager for execution
        // this job performs the following:
           // serialize location data to protobuf
           // encrypt protobuf
           // HTTP POST encrypted data to web server
    }
}
```

The job manager I reference above is basically a queue that 1) persists jobs in a Realm database and 2) executes the jobs in a FIFO order.

So far, this seems to be working as expected.  However, I've noticed that when the user presses the home button and my app is sent to the background/is suspended, I continue to get location updates but my HTTP POST seems to eventually stop working.

I'm using Alamofire 4.0.1 to make the HTTP POST.  I've added logging into the code and I see that the web request is being called every time:

```
NSLog("About to POST location data...")
// urlRequest.body = encrypted protobuf
alamoFireSessionManager.request(urlRequest).validate().responseJSON() {
    NSLog("Inside response JSON handler!")
    if response.result.isSuccess {
        NSLog("HTTP POST was successful!")
    } else {
        NSLog("HTTP POST failed!")
    }
}
```

As I said, when my app gets sent to the background/is suspended, I continue to get location updates and for a while, the HTTP POST continues to work properly (I can see the location data being received on the server).  However, eventually, I stop seeing data being POSTed to the server and I don't see any of the code inside the Alamofire response JSON handler execute.  In my app logs, I consistently see the string `"About to POST location data..."` but eventually the `"Inside response JSON handler!"` message stops appearing.

As I said, I'm fairly new to iOS so I may be missing something fundamental about how the OS treats background operations.  Is this behavior indicative of iOS allowing my app to work properly in the background for a while but then preventing it from making network calls eventually?  If so, is there another way to reliably perform a recurring HTTP POST at a specific interval while the app is in the background?

Answer (score 0):

Goto '**Capabilities**' under Target settings of the app, Enable Background modes and check mark the **Background fetch**. Try once, may it works for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, background fetch isn't a good solution for me because I can't control the interval that it occurs at.  As I understand it, BF is scheduled opportunistically by iOS rather than at a time of my choosing.  Thank you for the suggestion, though.

Comment: You can do another way also like creating a Background Task(UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier) in Appdelegate.